# Does the DLC for pokemon sword and Shield have version exclusive Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-isle-of-armor

I am wondering if I can catch all the basic forms in one game?  I know I will need to do some trading to get all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The DLC has version exclusive Pokémon just like the base game. For example, Clauncher is only available in Sword, whilt Skrelp is only available in Shield.

Comment: Do you know where to find a complete list?

Comment: The DLC has been out for... a few hours? Everything will be discovered eventually.

Comment: People have already completed the dex and done most of the activities.  So i assumed that there would be list out already.